# How to use a different branch for gitlab changelog generation

Tags: git, api, gitlab

I have to generate changelog from commits for a project. I was hoping to use the Gitlab API for the same.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#add-changelog-data-to-a-changelog-file

The generated changelog only works for commits in the master branch so how do we modify the api so that I can generate changelog for commits in other branch as well.

Comment: The API for changelog needs a required attribute `version`. It has other non-required attributes. `branch` is one of them, and it defaults to the project's default branch (`master` in your case). You can specify a branch with the attribute `branch` as how you specify `version`.

Comment: The branch attribute is the branch on which the commit will be made. It is not the branch which will be tracked for changes.

Comment: Use `from` and `to` to specify the commits.